# Select text in edit window using DPAD

Tags: android

I am using the DPAD controls to highlight text in android text-widget.

I am wondering is there is any way that when I highlight the text, it selects it also. Right now when I highlight and try to bring the context menu, the first context menu I get is the one with options to select word, select all etc. and when I do select word, it selects the entire region highlighted (which is okay, but I wanted it to select while am highlighting) so that I could get the cut/copy and paste context menu directly.